# Terminal Start up issue

Tags: bash, macos, performance, terminal

I want to speed up my terminal's load process because when I start it up it starts to run a something, and when I try to close the window it gives me this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xkWW.png which means that it might have to do bash profile which is:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
# added by Anaconda3 5.3.1 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
alias py="python"
alias cdpy="cd /Users/Sqirel4x2/BitsBobs/Coding/python"
alias editpro="sudo nanos ~/.bash_profile"
```

If anyone could help speed up my terminal load then that would be great.

Comment: Apparently this a known issue : https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10173#issuecomment-444243367

Comment: You first need to find where the overhead is, my guess would be the calls to `conda`, but if you need them then you need them.  There are probably some unnecessary variable settings there, but they won't make a huge difference.

Comment: Also, your `PATH` definition is buggy and contains redundant lines. You should only need `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"`  followed by `export $PATH`

Comment: Thanks, this really helped and it solved all of my problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What sped up my load speed was deleting Anaconda to test your time do: `time bash start` to troubleshoot this problem look at your bash profile by: `sudo nano .bash_profile` and then see what happens before you load up terminal.